# Javascript Map Set object reference: is this a standard to the language?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reference, pass-by-reference

I have tested this code

```js
const map1 = new Map();
let foo = function() {
  this.test = 1;
}
let foo2 = new foo();
map1.set('bar', foo2);

foo2.test = 2;
console.log(map1.get('bar').test);
// prints 2, not 1
```

on the code snippet section of

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set

However this behavior is not specified anywhere in the same document and I couldn't find any other reference by googling.

Notice that in the `Map.get` document, it is stated clearly that

> If the value that is associated to the provided key is an object, then
> you will get a reference to that object and any change made to that
> object will effectively modify it inside the Map object.

My question is, is the above `Map.set` behavior guaranteed to work in all implementations and all versions of javascript, or is the behavior not really standardized and can vary between versions.

Comment: Yes, `Map` is specifically designed so, that objects can be used as keys in a map. It's not available in all the versions of JS, only those implementing ES6 or later version.

Comment: As you have only *one* `foo` instance object, it is expected that it is *that* object which mutates, no matter where you reference it (in the map, in a variable, ...etc).

Comment: It has nothing to do with Map or Set, specifically, it's just how object references work in JavaScript. You could do `let bar = foo2;` and then `console.log(bar.test)` and it would show the same thing for the same reason: What gets stored in the Map (or the `bar` variable in my example) is a copy of the reference to the object, not a copy of the object. So when you change the object's `test` property, that changes the object; you see that change regardless of which copy of the object reference you're using.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt: *"My question is, is the above Map.set behavior guaranteed to work in all implementations and all versions of javascript..."* <== Yes, it is. This is fundamental to how JavaScript works, and defined in the specification.